# Convert date range into a numeric one

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I would like to create a new column by assign a numeric range depending on the column of years (from 1964 to 2017), in this case (from 0 to 53). Is it possible to do it in dplyr?

**Desired Output**

```
 years   number
 1964    0     
 1970    6
 2010    46
 2017    53
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(number = years-min(years))` should work fine, assuming you have `years` already inputted.

Comment: I have a problem using your code as I have two other variable columns "Main" and "Second", so my "number" column does not follow the "year" column. This is my code: `first_occurrences <- d.data %>% 
  select(year= Year, Main=IP1, Second=IP2) %>% 
  group_by(Main, Second) %>% 
  mutate(number = year-min(year))
  arrange(.[[1]])` I have tried grouping by year, but did not help. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: also put a `%>%` after the `min(year))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried anything along these lines?

```
x <- c(1964, 1970, 2010, 2017)

x - x[1]

[1]  0  6 46 53
```